# ADC with DMA on the STM32F411 is not working

Tags: stm32, dma, adc

I want to read 4 ADC channels (PA0,PA1,PA2 and PA3) in scan-continuous mode using DMA, the problem is that once the uC runs the program it just perform one ADC read sequence and then it gets "stuck", the code is still running but it is like it only allows for one ADC sequence conversion, here is the code.

```
#include "stm32f411xe.h"
int16_t adc_ch[4];
int main()
{
 //Enabling peripheral clocks*/
 RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
 RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_ADC1EN;
 RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN;  // Enable DMA2 clock  
                                                                                
//Pin A0-A3  as analog inputs
GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE0|GPIO_MODER_MODE1|GPIO_MODER_MODE2|GPIO_MODER_MODE3;    

// Configuring sequence for analog reading
ADC1->SQR1 |= 3<<20;                    // Configuring sequence length for 4 analog channels 
ADC1->SQR3 |= 0<<0;                     // A0 first in the sequence
ADC1->SQR3 |= 1<<5;                     // A1 second in the sequence
ADC1->SQR3 |= 2<<10;                    // A2 third in the sequence
ADC1->SQR3 |= 3<<15;                    // A3 forth in the sequence
// Setting ADC1 
ADC1->CR1 |= ADC_CR1_SCAN;          // Enabling scanning mode 
ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_DMA;               // Enabling DMA mode

//Setting DMA channel
DMA2_Stream0->PAR  = (uint32_t)(&(ADC1->DR));           // DMA source address
DMA2_Stream0->M0AR = (uint32_t)(&(adc_ch[0]));      // DMA destination address

DMA2_Stream0->NDTR = 4;                                     // # of transmissions
DMA2_Stream0->CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC                           // Enabling circular mode
                    | DMA_SxCR_MINC                         // Enabling memory (destiny address) increase after each transmission 
                    | DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_0                      // Peripheral (source) size set to 16 bits
                    | DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_0;                     // Memory (destiny) size set to 16 bits
DMA2_Stream0->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;                                        // DMA channel enable   

//ADC1 A0 config 
ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_CONT;
ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_ADON;
ADC1->CR2 |= ADC_CR2_SWSTART;

while(1)
{
}
```

}

Maybe something is missing, but I cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

You have to set also ADC1_CR2.DDS.